# How to run Excel macros when Excel files are opened through Automation Anywhere?

Tags: excel, vba, automationanywhere

I have two Excel files. One "MyMacro.xlsm" file, and a "MyPortfolio.xlsx" file. "MyMacro.xlsm" is designed to make changes to "MyPortfolio.xlsx". I will be adjusting the macro to accept an argument in AA later so I can run it against multiple separate files. But for now I'm just trying to make it run on its own.

When I manually open up the files, the macro works.

When I use Automation Anywhere to open the files, it always fails and and gives this error:

> Cannot run the macro 'ConvertTextToNumber'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

After that error, if I go to the already-opened "MyMacro.xlsm" file and try to run the macro manually, it fails and gives this error:

```
Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
```

If I close out the Excel files and open them up manually, it works again.

So something has to be breaking, caused by AA opening those files. Is there any way to run that macro without AA breaking it? Or am I missing something in how Automation Anywhere works with macros? I assume the sessions aren't recognizing separate open files.

Here are the two macros.

```vb
Sub ConvertTextToNumber()
Workbooks("My Portfolio.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A2000").NumberFormat = "General"
End Sub

Sub SortSmallestToLargest()
    Workbooks("My Portfolio.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:BT2000").Sort Key1:=Workbooks("My Portfolio.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), Order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like your two Excel files might be opened in two different Excel instances?

Comment: Is the macro security in your xlsm file set to auto accept?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, I think that is the issue. In Automation Anywhere each excel file gets its own session, and I think that prevents the macro in one 'session' to interact with the other 'session'...even though doing it all manually works just fine.

Comment: @ceci Yes, it is set to auto accept.

Comment: Maybe have the macro in MyMacro.xlsm open the other workbook directly.